# wordpress menu is acting strange

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am making a wordpress theme. Now I am working with menu. I have written these code in functions.php

```
register_nav_menus(array(
'topmenu' => 'Top Menu',
'bottommenu' => 'Bottom Menu',
'sidemenu' => 'Side Menu'
```

));

and these code in index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes();?>>
<head>
<meta <?php bloginfo('charset'); ?> >
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url');?>" />

<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class();?>>
<div id="page">
    <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
    'theme-location' => 'topmenu'
    ));?>
</div>

---------------
---------------
---------------
---------------
<div id="page">
    <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
    'theme-location' => 'bottommenu'
    ));?>
</div>      
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I Made a menu named "First Menu" and assigned it with 'topmenu'. But it appeared both in 'topmenu' and 'bottommenu'. Then I assigned it with 'bottommenu', the result is same. Then I assigned it with 'sidemenu', the result is exactly same.(Allthough there is no code for 'sidemenu' in index.php). Isn't it too much strange thing? Problems are not finished yet. I made another menu named "Second Menu" and assigned it with 'bottommenu'. Then "First Menu" disappeared from both location and  "Second Menu" was being visible. Now I want to know what mistakes I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong code, it should to be **theme_location**

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array(
'theme_location' => 'topmenu'
));?>
```

or You can use this one, 'First Menu' is name of the menu

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array(
'menu' => 'First Menu'
));?>
```